# Python CSV.Writer changing saving path

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, save, filepath

I would like to have my tkinter program prompt the user to select the path the want to save the file which will be produced by the program.

My code looks like this. At this stage the program only saves to one file (the one I defined to test the program)
What code would I use to have `'test_write.csv'` changed to any file the user chooses?

```
           ##Writing to .cvs file       
           with open('test_write.csv', 'w') as fp:
               a = csv.writer(fp)
               # write row of header names
               a.writerow(n)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for python3.xxx

```
   import tkinter
   from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

   with open(asksaveasfilename(), 'w') as fp:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [tkFileDialog module](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm).

Example:

```
import tkFileDialog
with open(tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(), "w") as fp:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint!!! I realize this would not work in python 3 See solution for this below. For those interested :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using [tkFileDialog](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm):

```
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import csv

formats = [('Comma Separated values', '*.csv'), ]

root = Tkinter.Tk()
file_name = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(parent=root, filetypes=formats, title="Save as...")
if file_name:
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
        a = csv.writer(fp)
        # write row of header names
        a.writerow(n)
```